# Templated Paginator in Blazor .net 8 always throws errors

Tags: pagination, blazor, .net-8.0

I am encountering an issue with my ASP.NET Core Blazor application. When making an HTTP request to a specific API endpoint, I'm getting a `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException` with the message "Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)."

*System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.g__Core|12_0[TValue,TJsonOptions](HttpClient client, Task`1 responseTask, Boolean usingResponseHeadersRead, CancellationTokenSource linkedCTS, Func`4 deserializeMethod, TJsonOptions jsonOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Dragon.Components.Pages.Tax.Add_Edit_Tax.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\Users\shatn\source\repos\Dragon\Dragon\Dragon\Components\Pages\Tax\Add-Edit-Tax.razor:line 211
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.g__ProcessAsynchronousWork|54_0()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.WaitForQuiescence()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(Int32 componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.EndpointHtmlRenderer.SendStreamingUpdatesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Task untilTaskCompleted, TextWriter writer)*

**Main.razor**
Below is the relevant code snippet where the issue occurs. It doesn't even print anything to the console in the try/catch block.

```
private List<Taxes> model;
private Helper.PaginatedList<Taxes> temp;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    try
    {
        temp = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Helper.PaginatedList<Taxes>>("/api/Taxes?skip=1");
        if (temp != null && temp.Items != null)
        {
            model = temp.Items;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected or null response from the API.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error during HTTP request: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

**Here is my controller method:**

```
// GET: api/Taxes
   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<ActionResult<PaginatedList<Taxes>>> GetTaxes(string skip)
   {
       var taxes = from s in _context.Taxes select s;
       return await PaginatedList<Taxes>.CreateAsync(taxes.AsNoTracking(), 0, Client.Constants.PageSize);
       //return await _context.Taxes.Skip(Int32.Parse(skip)).ToListAsync();
   }
```

**This is my Pagination class:**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dragon.Helper
{
    [JsonObject]
    public class PaginatedList<T>
    {
        public List<T> Items { get; set; }
        public int PageIndex { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }

        public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
            Items = items;
        }

        public bool HasPreviousPage => PageIndex > 1;
        public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

        public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }

}
```

I have spent several hours investigating this problem, including checking the correctness of the API endpoint, ensuring proper serialization of the server response, and adding error handling in my client-side code. Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated